# Apache2 configuration and security

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have installed apache2 under ubuntu 12.04.

**First**

I read the differences about mpm worker and prefork.  in my case it is in worker.  In my apache2.conf I have :

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

And a grep -ef | grep apache2 gives :

```
root      1189     1  0 13:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1192  1189  0 13:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1194  1189  0 13:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1195  1189  0 13:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

And I don't understand why there are 4 processes and why 1 is owned by root and the others by www-data.

**Second**

I also read it was not a good idea to set the /var/www with www-data as owner and group.
But I don't understand why ?

The good way would be to leave root as owner with full rights and the group to www-data with rx rights.  It's right ?

Answer (score -1):

**Root is the most secure**

Using root will keep any malware (People say linux cant get virus's but it might and it's good to be secure) from taking over your apache server, because root is a seperate account with extreme privileges. **Long story short just keep it in root.**

Comment: Sorry, but the opposite is true. The root account has the most privileges of all. If you're root on a machine, you can do just about anything - reading, changing or deleting any data, transferring any data to anywhere, using any resources of the machine and so on. When a program (technically, a process) is started, it normally gets the privileges of the user that has started it. If user 'joe' starts a program, it may do everything that 'joe' can do. If 'root' starts a program, it may do everthing that 'root' can do - which is, as I said, just about everything. So only use root if you have to.